# HTML gallery page in Swing with drag-drop functionality

Tags: java, html, image, swing

I was asked to write a `JDialog` separated into left and right panel. The left panel shows a demo HTML template gallery (small sized), and right panel shows series or list of images. I want to make it such that I can drag image on the list and place it on the gallery (or maybe drag out some image from the gallery). The problem is I don't know where to start with this, can anybody give me some idea?

Comment: *"HTML template gallery"*  What exactly is that?  I understand HTML & gallery (though I don't understand the relevance to Swing) but what DYM by 'template'?

Comment: I want to produce an html page that display thumbnail pictures (similar to a gallery). These images are imported from a folder (Load all images from that folder). Now, I have to make a UI for the user to customize the name and order of each image displayed on the html page.

Comment: @user385261 Javascript is powerful enough to handle this program itself. Are you sure you need Java to do this (because you're making it more complicated)?

Comment: It was required for a java swing application.

Answer (score 2):

An HTML gallery typically uses JS to do the 'heavy lifting' (I'm guessing it will require a slideshow as well).  While Swing components support HTML (to an extent) they do not support JS.

I recommend not trying to *render* the HTML/JS in the GUI, instead, provide a `JList` in the GUI of the image+name objects chosen by the user (using `JFileChooser`).  When each image is selected, you can show the 'preferred name' in a `JTextField` that allows the user to edit it.

Image order can be shown by the order in the list.  To change the order, implement Drag'n'Drop.  See the [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) lesson for more details.

You will probably need a `JLabel` in the `CENTER` of the GUI to display the (full size) selected image, and show the order & timing of the slideshow.

Once the user is happy with the image selections, the order, the names & timing.  Offer them a button to write all the details to a single directory including the HTML, script & images (easier).  Once the HTML is written, invoke `Desktop.open(File)` to display the finished product to the user.

As to how you do all that, it is really beyond the scope of an answer on SO.  You would need to do the tutorial on each part, and come back with more specific questions.